# Extracting HTML table from XML node in C#

Tags: html, xml, html-table, extract, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML from within an XML node:

```
<table cellpadding="5"><tr><td><strong>Date </strong></td><td><strong>Event</strong>
</td><td><strong>Pro</strong></td><td><strong>Act</strong></td><td>
<strong>Prev</strong></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 8 12:30</td><td>Announcement</td><td>0.300  
%</td><td>0.100  %</td><td>0.700  %</td></tr></table><br />

<h2>News</h2><ul><li><a href="http://www.link1.com">News Text</a> Source <br/>Fri, Jun 8 
2012, 12:34 GMT</li></ul><br /><div class="class1">
<a href="http://link2.com"><img src="http://link3.com" border="0"></img></a>
```

I need to be able to grab JUST the table. Unfortunately, all of this is inside of one XML node, so I can't use doc.SelectSingleNode any further. I'm going to parse the data that I get, but since the latter half of the elements change constantly, I have to be able to pass this to XElement.Parse as a variable and not as a static string.

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack. If anyone knows how to extract the table only, I'd greatly appreciate a point in the right direction as I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(descr.ToString(), @"<table\s*(.+?)\s*</table>");
```

I refuse to tell you what I was doing wrong :)